# How can I get full-ranged random float values?

Tags: java, random, floating-point

I found that [Random#nextFloat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextFloat--) returns a value between `0.0` and `1.0`.

How can I get a random float value such as `-72.0F` or `126.232F`?

I currently doing like this.

```java
float randomFloat() {
    final ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
    float value = random.nextFloat() * Float.MAX_VALUE;
    if (random.nextBoolean()) {
        value = 0 - value;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Is this right? Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I think you could call `random.nextInt()` and then use `Float.intBitsToFloat()`.  This might not be as random as you'd like, though, and you might have to deal with format errors in the bit patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest generating a bound double and then converting to float:

```
return Double.valueOf(random.nextDouble(Float.MIN_VALUE, Float.MAX_VALUE)).floatValue();
```

The `nextDouble` method has been replaced in Java 8 with a method to produce a stream of doubles. So in Java 8 you would use the following equivalent:

```
DoubleStream randomDoubles = new Random().doubles(Float.MIN_VALUE, Float.MAX_VALUE);
Double.valueOf(randomDoubles.findAny().getAsDouble()).floatValue();
```

Comment: This cannot produce any negative numbers. Also, if `random` is a java.util.Random, it does not have that method in JDK 1.8.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I have tested this and it happily produces negative numbers - I'm not sure where you got the view that it doesn't produce negatives. There is an equivalent method in Java 8: `doubles` that produces a stream of doubles. I'll add a Java 8 version to the answer.

Comment: The problem with this is that Random.doubles() or random.nextDouble() uses uniformly chosen double values between 0 and 1 and then scales them to fit the bounds. This means that certain values will be missing and some values will appear more often than others (though all in all, a histogram will likely not show this). @markspace has the right idea.

Comment: @llogiq given the double is then scaled back to a float anyway there won't be any missing or duplicate values. Using `intBitsToFloat` leaves you entirely at the mercy of the platform's implementation. You could well find on some platforms that this is not a portable solution. The one I gave is guaranteed by the language spec.

Comment: Could you post your test program? I get compilation errors because the result of the `findAny` call, an `OptionalDouble`, does not have a method `get`. The reason I do not expect negative results is that [Float.MIN_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#MIN_VALUE) is positive.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan typed that too quickly. I intended `-Float.MAX_VALUE` which is what I have in my test programme. Statement in my test code is `new Random().doubles(-Float.MAX_VALUE, Float.MAX_VALUE).limit(20).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan also replaced the `get` with `getAsDouble`.

Comment: I suggest copy-pasting the code from your test program directly into answers, rather than retyping with the inherent waste of time caused by posting obviously incorrect code. I am still not clear exactly how you intend this code to be used - do you create a new Random for each nextFloat call?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan fair point. I admit I rushed the answer and made a few mistakes I should have avoided. Generally you wouldn't create a new random each time you wanted a new float. Having said that whenever I've needed pseudo randoms I normally just scale from the 0-1 range methods or use % for ints.

Answer (score 2):

This is based on a the general idea in the [prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30587099/1798593), but fixes a small bug and shows how to actually write the method using JDK 1.8:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t = new Test();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      System.out.println(t.randomFloat());
    }
  }

  final ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
  Iterator<Double> randomDoubles = random.doubles(-Float.MAX_VALUE,
      Math.nextUp((double) Float.MAX_VALUE)).iterator();
  float randomFloat() {
    return randomDoubles.next().floatValue();
  }
}
```

The code in the question used ThreadLocalRandom, so I did the same. The Random `doubles` method excludes the upper limit. In order to get the required full range, use as limit the smallest double that is greater than all finite `float` values. Getting an `iterator<Double>` seemed simpler and more direct than using `findAny` etc.

Comment: Nice answer and a good idea converting the stream to an iterator.